Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed/ A connection to the MDM server could not be established
This is my mobile config file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AccessRights</key>
            <integer>8191</integer>
            <key>CheckInURL</key>
            <string>https://stgmdm.familytime.io/mdm/[[enrollhash]]/checkin</string>
            <key>CheckOutWhenRemoved</key>
            <true/>
            <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
            <string>XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures Mobile Device Management</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Mobile Device Management</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086.mdm</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ServerURL</key>
            <string>https://stgmdm.familytime.io/mdm/server</string>
            <key>SignMessage</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Topic</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086</string>
            <key>UseDevelopmentAPNS</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>     
        <dict>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>1234569</string>
            <key>PayloadCertificateFileName</key>
            <string>identity.p12</string>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <data>
            MIIZeQIBAzCCGT8GCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCGTAEghksMIIZKDCCE98G
            CSqGSIb3DQEHBqCCE9AwghPMAgEAMIITxQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwG
            CiqGSIb3DQEMAQYwDgQI6xD07eZLE8gCAggAgIITmC9aW1muG98N
            sUMXwcEAdoZv6oxVpbBZ2/W/wTrlKl/vHJn9NGlD1j16ortAsMQx
            KDGO8W0//wX/nngHbZCplQDO4dvckgkCjORxXcxorpmCxTRMn3Af
            nUFiIF8+Xg5rVgpc0NxjPQ7X/fjKxwOrvOgSw5vBqkDAl6BH9XvM
            RhZ6RxtJ3fftZCJaQelCV4cYHiQ+L6l/Nsx16XyRm8Cgmi56JbK8
            Pqk8jnLvvWS9G3L4akBUk5pBm68w7NDOziKDNzIS6AEQSHp2rn2U
            qBg0nLn9XMndqRX4sv1imVLlTWz1srnfZ8sQZGoeXVHiOJUYurb7
            UAH75fnjvDmJu4gPx9QeEdxkLyxI59HNj7zdHw80EMEFSoMYxO2y
            dYBCxQZLJM1MTn+ppDJcK6BDkL2cuDOvZeF2HQEITwA0gP8DfGus
            Tptei9xzomZmsjMiKJWmu+hbpmKUVVZTVzwETH8S0453tJbTtYx+
            ytUCgDE4G99OCtGJC7xCEDlEmjCvED7ACAu3zm06UJZGvzl8MHpH
            41nUyw8GUk/NgILmNWpb7l4mcZaPyEskQbuuI3HWAzZWFJJgb1t8
            Uhs35KWetwJq3ZnSgbo/t48M2QuWr48CKbvOaoLvYolm9+a41OPV
            wacs02+p4hFpq2vm36cLmEARxCECgucYQmExdOmBp0qjEWg7pGKt
            kEgKBqs4BZeO7+l3NpDhj/Na8YOLgw9iI1KqPl/XbxQduKAz+GT7
            n3roK6AZLKXyCl20XLmlmzQ0HDtdWEdgM3781lFtjfqnC6OivuHJ
            kzxAZB7ww6TX4EUyyBCaTWoIFSj975ZBOEb7v8bsjA7FUtYe+S12
            wNnDoHnhyD7BRcnWLlZ73/Z2OwYOjAGSjB0ApKohuMsFN+xbJ4d9
            VUxypddJBTSdHqUPsKhEQGAeC6Tmm1g1py++L4RAjM8s5FLnR+0Q
            y+unCHShWqx0DBj5KBeSdi0xbXT2H56Q97Z0C9UvBo4MywcKYreQ
            Xm3iol14fG8Vur1VjNjRpxdPw5fCIRdstgWOMw9iJcW6v2NqHo11
            cwYNMqnu/hotKHf5VqggG2gRzJ/7vUlrFegb02+yLsa1VJU9hWBX
            F7kDJG6tNGLGLyAGOVtBiWRzhkDW+/0uGye2MHiRPdk3LlB4aUNc
            txSfZNQaJAyB2O6d2WiNgMtLauw6yqcOmcZIIy2FjNzND9+4I1wZ
            d+fPIMq92ljvHWLdv3FAOrvDvBpHLWbqd5aFNgbPBOlflDqlGxgM
            vJno1V5ko0GwhPGu5sc2x63M01PLzZ+1kpgH1ry8tVaVH597bxAq
            I3m7fBEJgSqi3VSMqIvk+5H8eqx0ibVuM63IJpCMty3ImCTsodqk
            /Kqrju7jZrKhxO9iksJTgguTyHAEwtbZ0GMdntQZVlcaMuOAuMrn
            CiTzSW65SeA39gO0jQGwVZWqV2R4JKgqGdteuhBWV7BofKVpvrh6
            LAjzNIp6bDK2eu7uCvuDpKNePzEdiRH3vfWgg84qebpXm7i1Pel8
            p7Dvg23WSGdB2K0QklQP4QZVVUW8f/xRh9OUI0G7fek6k1MvKel6
            xSzxENWDO96CPY87waXR9zpAkwhxKEtHoIXoOx8tVOjVg7jfCh4b
            Rr07CsCuZ5O0ax5L44q+/HKbsBzY/GFAjHc13Xlcz1os/jzqOcsc
            MdPzxDnTgiba9EK6dFvMqhlDJZo5SMuaog2JywWGXbj0ilA6LBrp
            Bw+bOKmvTnO1XIrkxLFZRNLEktivLNrxbVBbPHCnS4Iy4y77aHhw
            Lgw5ySOQgMb63eGbXJVO9nG14qJ/sejXOQ41cWdzvZCMBX8RPMXQ
            ejafyM+bJ5spAiAbMDMZyN9KiEFW9ipcyKfUfTPYwZ/cUY09L2O5
            Fb7RTEXVS3NKenVV4J2vfs93NSNqHyIFkAwbJlfkOS+n/l32byEA
            BiXSTJDZK5i0OfcDgadaGRqS7OzeXYaBSNBbVXPbAJyDbjZJQsHc
            TdcK39xfClhZi3HQNRQgmoZ6hai/rM+aKKRMmenQijDPO6NW1+KH
            yEqSY0avG+hIbflNINkF6m/PvFI5E8/DAabuQDtjkrycIWQiz3JJ
            lVTJAlDF4mqnyhLZLxOMr0bwjvrxCy9vOovokCRuLyDB31X04lMR
            IZOKSAAhm8tEsLOgu9da0phXsf/HknH785d5/v7zJtQkBVyiHOU/
            30/tXz49k7xFr03zZjoy6UwhBWp5/mIVUAudBNjHvhmhHV5711LN
            wAvsEg1Ot07l+7ErbVPeRvXo02ADGBtLaNOCF5ylQzC4oCqMwN4s
            2+VeXndfnVwUcYS4gejHYPdqT34xBPC+paO3hYgYjwuy0fKznjp7
            +JMsvW27SXoD0VuNLBsS0BeS/Rf6U5rqxWGvUVWqrkjsXKwJCZKN
            Z2R+0gTgpn1vJI4uC8J23BDNUFUJl1hTArlk2/3hHJiDnmYaNROF
            CpJAxbhB0kOwcWmfay9VsJNTEyTpONPl0heGSMU8rBM0l6gpgpnt
            dyaljZoJMHRfB29oCUxAZHNfOuqk4NexNv+SYEMGtcri4ygANPJ9
            JhNNMSIA/thZB4Lcqak1hpLywAy01dOAe3F1fGCj9faMdJWXFOoq
            +XD3bWVfAcZ2ayuUj0FVDsEqmz0i47lWoG4Cf8ly0YV0m1yXUZmI
            xwFY98iMGg8AuxH2wKVJ5+/VLtalRq+9ZUp432TAJ+Tnr2tMT78M
            TT/JCX5Q7wyKvtMiuMddsJmHLelJh78837G1BKk6e7dZGN2UTtcP
            1LmOQrjhSKAPpEpZ0PXeoXFVrZayxU1Ngnzc7+8FwVnU0t7+zcDf
            D0Cw4idpVEVlIiSyVuABAiT/bnlVSj1UJ3FuncWlgvRjeCMtaiBV
            pq/pU/S+4dDcPpluLUi36qu0CHLp7p1Mh2xGGqW0CBUQmnD9W0NM
            hfpWzt6/BcotWoCCNCg7nNyCd5eWnPZo2bstl2boX0gNIm28Uvxc
            cavfqwKDzfurXPfmz0lY6gyuiurKBq2z/6ZyrFnhuwYuNqeKb7Bm
            vu59qwRAGPB66nHnh3sc0uWJw70lvGOEx0Rdc6cicn+OY+e+l3lx
            EfQ02lr1EpYa5Qi/Jt3F6b5fv4D2M3OjKXgvGwP2RJiqdVd7fvXT
            LXwUzRhYbyLSzb5OJ7tKZ7Ud29hxBRyEKD4FZj7DI8K2vkEQjjGu
            Pc0yT83ofFpBuwbq3XjaPt7/h0HTxg/3gnrjam9tDbbcZrwUyUYE
            +I20VWUX6FBtiTGE5TzCSrALRjsypwF+FyaDOxIEFeremmqp9kyd
            z7J59iakaN6hTm6CJ0vJGQVXEAX+aM6hde1FNceZEGEmSy2FCTqY
            UQqfLLvJZ5gqGUlwmm2wCKmJkOB3UFXbFCFy8Kd1EOBS2AoKQ9Ss
            ZaRsXheU9GtQzyHlFiopBCak6tmF6EiMmvGJLdHLiIUKOLSlhe22
            a/161PciFAv0W6V3D3dOLzXnNe3eRiY2ecSS/ZVNEGL3r0IO+V4D
            tDxasAWfOcix2MDqF9Oi2B7mcKqNYNH1k30pw5p6tgsGFGbf31Uo
            JLXCoJoPJqpYsRkfJ4gTnghPaaA731YfpffgkiWOSRcZ6YWxvFLQ
            U4+16wVwTjxQzkR5Zi/CPmMH/xxIMwHfBJueByNtN1252ehJ3cmN
            PG6DCIfFTu/VsqK+BrTTjgU7AEy0QmaX+40EjPAd+bt50i6zbCPy
            2mZ0g17wPkQSe2zX/Vh6bgveovKd0WoJ0lgX24Kb1kJ6O0oiXek/
            Rf8TRD6i697zdg38N9rN3GobzvgjobZxruwqz0VZDFBKTg3apWu3
            ZgMEaEgjVyWbJ8iLQbTZ3Tq3potGCvQlSDxKuaepdqgjrf/5xd/T
            VzspZWZW5QTetXOjsBgdRcj0Kh0phQ/H/Bdt61aY4U7Qzdlc1d9i
            8FLfvvv990I3A7RWM4Ch1O0k1uhFAe7Wlo9h7hiLkcarpKMp+78D
            8uP/b83dAlCqw0Tefmva/XzRSkcBycuCU52A5FdmhZ9JyKV6WnE8
            lwuaVAahqYUZDXUibQy8LLU/TUYW5sEIafdrqL2aVfH3IiKAS48B
            bILySFoSsrhPYVac3ROxzqkHaaFs1MeYw/BzRagP5qC6Rf7d280r
            Sl98Fp2unx8RCfm7yFyqIix5nMRveheCnVis3bPRrcFoMl5gW5AZ
            QZ8enxzrFO/MWxplZNAa4RoZsdIInnY/jp/CWs9OAvY7jmD2qRjA
            4w1/ryx52R7T4Y09OWyoRpJ/JeZ/B1MVlYAi6LaBkk+y4LkaRDKm
            +l0MwiLa6pCz7i8etlMAEx3++OiaFRbx6QdHeddLRDiPZ3pqTOAc
            iZ98uROPPdbHbXcuw9VeNutaYjSukaWwTfHWCLhIkmVvbCyRDGz1
            WtqbWfyeiU4Tzi3byPuLH9wRWOeFIQDQUpS2eZn7T5QNvPDuXJHI
            w1jSkkyPLX64+i8D70UUJLBvyZs0DIQN56PLy2ZgK7KJ4Ksqf+I7
            7oLEsd1Jvkneoqag9SKP5KgATs+70Vh3r91Ny8dXLUFiHJR7rVnv
            tCelBm/JHXXLmcZJBg1nT/Xcpkivx2IF/0cFskxy70RSHLAd2pOj
            H4ZnaGptmwGAEwZgajV8ZxXdRr0TzgZLvjuiOEVNtguqHuPgCB20
            g0/7D9oe/oFWEO7wg+y85zyahL4S21dtkQILHQbsRXx1TubnkP9W
            okjw0DrQ1bcov+EjROABpX8XKTdep6FgvsV/fLkENw8E14CrVE9Q
            7VZ22hFcq0fNm9lqFLt7CkLhgP701AWFbbn0jnLtzrtjB/Xvsmo2
            Pci7d+GQrXJaHB1qrqsH9ywgqT/MvPJoSkTUx6fgosRNx6MdXjZq
            F5zYT3hjrtBMZ5nubzv0AYzc0kgqm3HQ+eRb7elMGFkS15B66GVI
            aiPPz1YueAuxsDbky96Dve8fjfFCy7nxrK6ErzfZkfJQfkC6Bkr4
            znd4iN/ibyf7h5kFwYSL/G43lfkh5douirbIHUEYyGpn76ymNGeu
            dAKq29E1LzAxiDugjUp+gFWOqRKHFiV4P79NPgg4vIxWd9ob58C/
            kMJomtceTIW/z6xqKl4gVUAqpkEiECj6dQm0pkmNVcAK9Mf1xGM9
            D5+sWmymUFE5l9bauQ/ZS77fLINNw0Zm+TEwd2QWRNz26fQAN6Nk
            A51CMVeeStrVlMuvNwu4FaZ6iVOesq9YFZIlwS3l7eXQxQQyRUnP
            J7fmdo42VFZX4NPk7LGQOi3nx78cob7ocFqy2ncQlRveLPSjHtFP
            FeA7/qTsIOBAxRGKO4QO6A8ser58LR/QfHBAG9jlgSu1Ah8t/fCf
            YJ4SXV3X/wY5I72lH+MmVq3uVb+Wm2RnAQ+5D8iiYPx/N7R8gsU2
            gV0Wm3KGjmHI8msxXq8SByzCKpWsk46pqDL2+YLXTQ5lYmmjy3Q4
            oM0TA4ge8fumNhcdWCv7E5fAYpbbz5JMHLZO5RP3Ph9WHgajK6Wg
            QKbBXUX6HBO3WvriwLjnTMalC5s33su+UekcTQmyEMEKD+0ilPdZ
            1L86XHhu8VwVxyULmy0s7YwnfMh/i6wuGFGgDaVTLI7uJ6sRu1cK
            yUFJJyR0nZw2r9emC6tfE7G5U2ar0dh+O147gPALqGdNBtp1dvFC
            lGCddy5dCjPGzAn2Itpw4PkBXpN4Fvrcd/jJ3DE4mso4PwS0QqsO
            vJdxfSo6tOQD/OqIwRzZ+4Al8P1GN20mbQKHcJMMgd4/Ia68Aq4S
            GSy6dqmJe+kWITwnxNEePZxuuEKaC4SyHWcSWrNaUhCg4g4h9Twj
            F5CV6XzVcHvf1qzKxiTHqz/hgJdpq9TuSV2lWZ1jiaSnktN5o/kB
            U5bULQiUn1rmYY+6N0wpyDCCBUEGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBTIEggUu
            MIIFKjCCBSYGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE7jCCBOowHAYKKoZIhvcN
            AQwBAzAOBAivHPaHvWjFWgICCAAEggTIfjNqfLcceBrtBcqH/T2P
            dJnHHn9vHggUlra2YvgxYIHP3AMZ216YppoaBrKsEZ/5iZO/cD1L
            wXeFAZKNPfD2kzi6HddN249jcmuqPihWyJMlFhSBasle4Sj7nkZo
            gDLDyidxWc9VFjxWVQQnSyg6TL0wp84raAUTzRiF/KGvIfs/M2fu
            awKYr0E+xPwdQz0Xm2CkSs1Xb0uh/7a+xdz1Rnk1uq+NM9xdHGsg
            URyyK81aY0ix2NHs/RHwYxL0WDYl+1zRFIdEoYS3XYMMHfSMu7xa
            pN5DRyUCAy2uo6CWf4OEvGg91nhEOibl1uO8PktQYEvwCjuEKQWF
            T1ytO1ZS0S8uEkBMyM5NqD84lM/OW8ew91GmiTJlBJi3EK9/Xuzn
            hC5XigOCxcx3IBudf0rT20GrOKMvStxN2bLJEfDBhzIpUY4RO2cH
            erhZNph+ivEWZLd7M6nOj8UT2gynqWcc4fjO1naZNYADUwB4RIhn
            /kDM/4sxWEJym80eIqy1UV4MRaxZRTPB6UKRPxBUYdAc1pkn+OEj
            xHd4NdvoV0DwVP8Xgi9dwm2xxMEj0lq3T14MThhPX3kWO5uGO60o
            KWwtwhlMPvT5CKqBKFTn8dNKm+oelFblCBRmBj5HHAQKskpbRHcS
            +5FO1trnlNdZsu3Bl78SEJuK8/K+y5HPMAZ8i/NuBxG5Hl+K9sb3
            B9GEa2E0FvqLmw1duiLPNOn87t+tG3rcf0uRGSIoCkVZg5yHURSL
            f57Z+h0ivgT2StPNQ459Sq2BmidQTeKoYvphuDxD/x7FiK5bd6o9
            qNyHfMhTX4vSZ0BA1m2Jx+Ecm2jbaRxsTR5/pIQoc1ZDEd1ansr/
            9NbQ27SSGvhLjc+9nvxpXRFEcvYLmQECUmsyb+VaMKwI9Ijzmq+5
            oKAKesBhFX5YVuTkFp8apkJwFYfKM63wh12z74i51o8QD339p8IX
            21cNg2GfedbNqV8qPEhXm4Au5qDbCtttvmCvOt6GwUlJsuSYls8W
            WggZ2RZe0y8b2tgPFiS6WyYny28481wRLVFRgVRF52a/qKj2iqkK
            dcN2WBuwkmemfEGV68wqrso7lGOvkMpYS/e1A0tPx5VsKx3ywQgP
            UDcv74GGqvuKM5CMe1qdsqAd8rL8Jia4/g3bxqPu4y732NUzQRMb
            Hjb5zcMK1fL2cmBTUer5qOzcORymMxiI5gk2/oJ5tLjiMaCJeVme
            rxF5iE4+mWxcTRZBGiNzeRwsF3PoGXmYVaiAt4VuMwPfgNtbRFI+
            QXK/qpj3r3mUnedmRk4deUakn6k/6gjBhEMsdW621631So7edhb8
            kxHy+bnsioDfYdSpHzVraMhrRlPMgzjuHoHNhWbpr925Iyq6Efdc
            R79qYgysUoKIbnbgDqRjQofuSS6ouXy7FwtsuDmgT7EXEzVxLJhY
            N66gFdlU8AkhiztWmeAKJ6Ac25zmk4A/geIUc+71jr6KIXwEmFN8
            eSz8jsY4mJ9ZDcNn+W5DlhgvyR0e1rvPlJuAC1N+rmNcnnQ1YQ/1
            ZX7iy7Gz9flMh/gCk9N/XzmuAV91KV+FN0uYIXxZjBY+Oajh9dw6
            KkoaESocfNCROukF92fSg1EbowQqNVGXm28PsBT/r1gmDgHxlKYn
            MSUwIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkVMRYEFD9S32mFA8qZlyUMpqPzwxVYz7q3
            MDEwITAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBRMoz/XfqZhNdULLzYFKw17rVmqVAQI
            Ji3sNUxTezoCAggA
            </data>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Adds a PKCS#12-formatted certificate</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>FamilyTime MDM</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086.credential1</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>7E62C82D-65F6-44AB-9B5D-5D33E800E3BF</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadCertificateFileName</key>
            <string>familytime_io.crt</string>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <data>
            LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUdOakNDQlI2
            Z0F3SUJBZ0lRZEpzN013S05CVTM3Z0E0b0czaDFiekFOQmdrcWhr
            aUc5dzBCQVFzRkFEQ0IKanpFTE1Ba0dBMVVFQmhNQ1IwSXhHekFa
            QmdOVkJBZ1RFa2R5WldGMFpYSWdUV0Z1WTJobGMzUmxjakVRTUE0
            RwpBMVVFQnhNSFUyRnNabTl5WkRFWU1CWUdBMVVFQ2hNUFUyVmpk
            R2xuYnlCTWFXMXBkR1ZrTVRjd05RWURWUVFECkV5NVRaV04wYVdk
            dklGSlRRU0JFYjIxaGFXNGdWbUZzYVdSaGRHbHZiaUJUWldOMWNt
            VWdVMlZ5ZG1WeUlFTkIKTUI0WERUSXpNVEl4T1RBd01EQXdNRm9Y
            RFRJMU1ERXhPREl6TlRrMU9Wb3dHakVZTUJZR0ExVUVBd3dQS2k1
            bQpZVzFwYkhsMGFXMWxMbWx2TUlJQklqQU5CZ2txaGtpRzl3MEJB
            UUVGQUFPQ0FROEFNSUlCQ2dLQ0FRRUF2UnVjCjZQSmJFVWQxWDZ2
            Z3grMnhZdzRSTVg1dmc4eTNqenM4VTR0NTVhZ0s0cE1Ed2JKNkUz
            UjNWd0h6V0xIMDZxdzkKWC91RGppRHRUVXZzUHNscWlaQXJvd0FO
            NEpacGhLZ1F5UXp6VGxDejJ4TDVvUzV2bkpKcmphK3NnSGhjWFZv
            VwpRWTJYdWhpSzdGb3V0LzVtVDVhVzI3ZmVlSFRTajIyS0RadXZs
            VXBZNE1TUjlEWmk0eElZMDIveHlxS1l6d2V4CjRNM0M2eW0rUEhY
            ZE4wU0tpWTZhaExnKzZQbkFRZDgrUHRvT1BrZHVvdmFJR0FFYWd6
            Yy8wbHMvTVA4T1pvQy8Kem1QNmhha0xjU1NxVEZzTk1xMmh0My9i
            N2FYRmNaZ1pJNHAxTndOMVZicHdQVWpnYisyV1hXL2JCekx4aU9B
            cwp4bnRVcllISmMvZGcrbUs1eVFJREFRQUJvNElEQURDQ0F2d3dI
            d1lEVlIwakJCZ3dGb0FVall4ZXhGU3RpdUYzCjZadjVtd1hodUFH
            TlllRXdIUVlEVlIwT0JCWUVGT0JZeUNyQzV5OWVsRUhjVTgxaFQw
            ZUJlRXF0TUE0R0ExVWQKRHdFQi93UUVBd0lGb0RBTUJnTlZIUk1C
            QWY4RUFqQUFNQjBHQTFVZEpRUVdNQlFHQ0NzR0FRVUZCd01CQmdn
            cgpCZ0VGQlFjREFqQkpCZ05WSFNBRVFqQkFNRFFHQ3lzR0FRUUJz
            akVCQWdJSE1DVXdJd1lJS3dZQkJRVUhBZ0VXCkYyaDBkSEJ6T2k4
            dmMyVmpkR2xuYnk1amIyMHZRMUJUTUFnR0JtZUJEQUVDQVRDQmhB
            WUlLd1lCQlFVSEFRRUUKZURCMk1FOEdDQ3NHQVFVRkJ6QUNoa05v
            ZEhSd09pOHZZM0owTG5ObFkzUnBaMjh1WTI5dEwxTmxZM1JwWjI5
            UwpVMEZFYjIxaGFXNVdZV3hwWkdGMGFXOXVVMlZqZFhKbFUyVnlk
            bVZ5UTBFdVkzSjBNQ01HQ0NzR0FRVUZCekFCCmhoZG9kSFJ3T2k4
            dmIyTnpjQzV6WldOMGFXZHZMbU52YlRBcEJnTlZIUkVFSWpBZ2dn
            OHFMbVpoYldsc2VYUnAKYldVdWFXK0NEV1poYldsc2VYUnBiV1V1
            YVc4d2dnRitCZ29yQmdFRUFkWjVBZ1FDQklJQmJnU0NBV29CYUFC
            MQpBTThSVnU3VkxueXY4NGRiMldrdW0ra2FjV2RLc0Jmc3JBSFNX
            M2ZPekRzSUFBQUJqSC9IaEtnQUFBUURBRVl3ClJBSWdRRHY0Yzds
            U3JuNEQ5R1lMQXZNdjdWVWFYQVV4b0ovUHJFQ3pWckROdHNJQ0lI
            ek1FMXJ1dnBBTEFIY0EKVG5XakoxeWFFTU00VzJ6VTN6OVM2eDN3
            NEk0YmpXbkFzZnBrc1dLYU9kOEFBQUdNZjhlRWhBQUFCQU1BU0RC
            RwpBaUVBbG5aVDBrTXNjOGRwMmFtNnpDMDgybEQyZ0tnNnZWMjAz
            ZldEd1RFT1U1Y0NJUUNPaXBXTGNHeEhsUGdPCkExVW1VVExvTkVL
            THNIRkc0Si8zdW10eHQzOUoxVEFOQmdrcWhraUc5dzBCQVFzRkFB
            T0NBUUVBaDNNQ2FzeHoKNmc4ZmdNQ3NQRUVrZnJmc2xKSGk1Qm56
            b1RhNE1qdDkvZnJGK1B3dzhMdFBwZFVVU1JkRVhBTjBmWjRTbG50
            UgpiOVp1aTg0akthMXJJTFNaeHNFUXZHVndtaUZ4MS9GYnN5Qnd1
            cTZxbFdvejI1UzJub2UrWFVOdnJ5MEdsdE54CkpjL00vNEwxZXRH
            cjN0TTVFZnMxMEl3UWpsZ1dpWHNLZkhPVTBJUWZUUnowZ0E3REdt
            NytZOGJCYWM4RXF0K3IKeUN2dUwvR08rY0F3TThMamhQbG5Ecmdu
            TDYvbHVicHhZaHZUOTUwVTFzYXVmcmVpQnhjVjdwWFA2VVhrZEVk
            TQpWelZYdEZxdWt6UmFWVnUyL1lXQTRZN1lTbzRZNThhTm1YZ2dL
            KytNbTVVRjVoa3U3K0Rpckl6bUwrWDE3ZlhwCnIyT2NuYU93ZFo1
            RVJRPT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
            </data>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Adds a PKCS#1-formatted certificate</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>FamilyTime Root CA</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.security.pkcs1.89877CBE-5F37-4FC2-82BF-13C5CEB9BFC1</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.security.pkcs1</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Install this profile to ensure proper functioning enhance device security.</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Device Security Profile</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>Familytime</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>


Downloaded succussfully in Iphone. But when i try to install and request the checkin url i get this response.
request.body:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\n<plist version="1.0">\n<dict>\n\t<key>BuildVersion</key>\n\t<string>20H343</string>\n\t<key>MessageType</key>\n\t<string>Authenticate</string>\n\t<key>OSVersion</key>\n\t<string>16.7.8</string>\n\t<key>ProductName</key>\n\t<string>iPhone10,3</string>\n\t<key>SerialNumber</key>\n\t<string>GHLYG03TJCLC</string>\n\t<key>Topic</key>\n\t<string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086</string>\n\t<key>UDID</key>\n\t<string>37333c34e041d3b39cf422ce5ef20e2997f334cd</string>\n</dict>\n</plist>\n'

MessageType : Authenticate
This mean according to MDM officail ducomentation.
The server shouldn’t assume that the device has installed the MDM payload at this time
: MDM URL
I want to this response. For management MDM:
Plist form:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">\n<plist version="1.0">\n<dict>\n\t<key>AwaitingConfiguration</key>\n\t<false/>\n\t<key>MessageType</key>\n\t<string>TokenUpdate</string>\n\t<key>PushMagic</key>\n\t<string>146E8420-F5EF-4182-9C22-6A5DA40D5C85</string>\n\t<key>Token</key>\n\t<data>\n\tmaT5C8OBllrMGMUuk3UR9/ihqvGg0b3TKWWG3oCQaZ8=\n\t</data>\n\t<key>Topic</key>\n\t<string>com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086</string>\n\t<key>UDID</key>\n\t<string>37333c34e041d3b39cf422ce5ef20e2997f334cd</string>\n\t<key>UnlockToken</key>\n\t<data>\n\tREFUQQAABPRWRVJTAAAABAAAAAVUWVBFAAAABAAAAAJVVUlEAAAAEAmm51PPnk99lE4a\n\tOWxj7OhITUNLAAAAKJ7PkTUvgqBudUih/w+5oHitkV24ybnzDMhu09We5gUDMvvfzWf+\n\txDFXUkFQAAAABAAAAAFTQUxUAAAAFDvXfa3nqTYR/gKJkLt2NGNWixniSVRFUgAAAAQA\n\tAMNQVVVJRAAAABC8nQF0PDFKi4FPPv9418tBQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAALV1JBUAAAAAQAAAAD\n\tS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACgaOfqTgrP43LqnAnbD3oiBPOoTCCmgs2Wtf+kBjVQL\n\t79VIE6vSjW6pVVVJRAAAABCxYlu4VnxEe4GrKdbT8jHXQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAAKV1JBUAAA\n\tAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACjfmeS6uHUiCR0EeM+53e4kWwatYQgkE0lf\n\tKLjKQdC8zKFaeKtMsQMpVVVJRAAAABDPubGtfohI1Y0ZCsL/6yt6Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAAJ\n\tV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACg4K0g8MhteRUAZdhi/sLpKKCJ6\n\tOU1IkurmdDChFEIj7gcHfx1mA/tQVVVJRAAAABDA26c9aDBF4ozhRkc5aQAtQ0xBUwAA\n\tAAQAAAAIV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACg1u4aSiO8hCP540Sh0\n\tHhhYfOlWANNaoVxgIqnOY7Bqceafd+xJZdpZVVVJRAAAABAX1aTZMkVCgLm/dGEE4/F+\n\tQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAAHV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACj3DcxmFlgQ\n\tjLz701W3r+RtnkiaLFNPK+TgJ2oeHfi4iLCNlLgTTd45VVVJRAAAABBUpCX64wFMcIdw\n\tfHD7pMiFQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAAGV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAACj/\n\tMJqNNzbgkhmQgc3+F00kLZVh0khxr+rkNm24CxA3QK445suerWC5VVVJRAAAABC5zkO/\n\tM9RD8I7RrcHbYJRrQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAAFV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BL\n\tWQAAACinw+4TkMC/JXgnJ13lFaBOCTWEc3JWIcPstpQYleu8YBHt7P8L1V2kVVVJRAAA\n\tABDxsatZjuFPwr8QJUlGFx1ZQ0xBUwAAAAQAAAADV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQA\n\tAAAAV1BLWQAAACi07GWGR3QTIVZGI+4OBZyBhuVEC0Ukavf5Tlc+kYLyjFH6ATLXJJ3b\n\tVVVJRAAAABCBqzqkOsZGBL4PaLAxyLy8Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAACV1JBUAAAAAQAAAADS1RZ\n\tUAAAAAQAAAABV1BLWQAAACifuh/NmLdzNSoi0vxGiT2SVY+SZ4NyQ1TQyXW5MGy0smNZ\n\tgMPwDAd4UEJLWQAAACCpKv3FTY/EzxyCvToc3y9hjw0wPP0DlQcoiexlyvejH1VVSUQA\n\tAAAQW7QKWoOGS/CvPKkDWYSkp0NMQVMAAAAEAAAAAVdSQVAAAAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAE\n\tAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoSG9X+e/pASYH1oDbHwySRmRV1/oF1AwPMI6efmxNcetJYXZMklwT\n\tvVNJR04AAAAUQ3QuYdHAfxoJekm/oc5HX7yi9eM=\n\t</data>\n</dict>\n</plist>\n'

Json type:

{'AwaitingConfiguration': False, 'MessageType': 'TokenUpdate', 'PushMagic': '146E8420-F5EF-4182-9C22-6A5DA40D5C85', 'Token': {'data': 'maT5C8OBllrMGMUuk3UR9/ihqvGg0b3TKWWG3oCQaZ8='}, 'Topic': 'com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086', 'UDID': '37333c34e041d3b39cf422ce5ef20e2997f334cd', 'UnlockToken': {'data': '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'}}

Please give the solution why not install MDM Payload.
